# Flutter : get appbar's height - Iphone 14 Pro Max

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, safearea

I have an appbar in my flutter app.
I'm use an padding to display a container

```
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
top: kToolbarHeight + kTextTabBarHeight,)
```

With Android and all iphone devices, that's ok like this image

[image]

But with Iphone pro 14 max and Safearea feature, my padding is not working (see image)

[image]

Should i have to add a constant in my padding to support "SafeArea iphone 14 max pro" feature ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it with SafeArea as you mentioned also if you can share the repo link it will make things easier

Comment: Sorry but hen i talked about "Safearea" i didn't talk about safearea flutter widget but i talked about " Apple dynamic island status bar height"

Answer (score 0):

How about `kFloatingActionButtonMargin + AppBar().preferredSize.height + kTextTabBarHeight`